# CPP: How to get last index of a char?

Tags: c++

I have this word occurrences example:

```
size_t count_occurrences(const char* s, const char* f){
    size_t t1 = strlen(s);
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t j = 0;
    size_t k = 0;
    size_t res = 0;
    auto nn = new char[t1+1];
    memcpy(nn,s,t1+1);
    char tok[200];
    while(i < t1){
        if(nn[i] == ' ' || nn[i] == '\0'){
            while(j < i){
                tok[k] = nn[j];
                k++;
                j++;
            }
            tok[k] = '\0';
            k = 0;
            j = i+1;
            if(strcmp(tok,f) == 0) res++;
            *tok = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return res;
}
```

So in my main function:

```
char str1[] = "Hi today is monday yeah";
char str2[] = "yeah";
size_t cont = count_occurrences(str1, str2);
cout << "The word: " << str2 << " repeats: " << cont << " times." << endl;
```

It doesn't works because i need to add an ' ' blank character at the final of str1 as below:

```
char str1[] = "Hi today is monday yeah ";
char str2[] = "yeah ";
```

How can i compare if the last index is 'null' in my while loop to make it work? I tried adding the sentence in the OR operator: `while(nn[i] == ' ' || nn[i] == '\0')` as can you see, but it not works.

Comment: This task should be done into separate parts. Part 1: take a single character string, and split it into a separate list of words, using whitespace, and perhaps punctuation, as delimiters. Part 2: simply search the list and count how many time your word appears. Both parts 1 and 2 are trivial, elementary tasks, together much simpler than trying to do everything in one step, which inevitably leads to tortured logic, and a bunch of difficult edge cases. As you've just discovered by yourself.

Comment: All true, but doesn't answer his question about checking for the null-termination of the string.

Comment: Yeah i just need to get the null-terminator to get in the while loop for the last token

Comment: This looks like an interesting thought experiment: what is going to take less time -- scrap the whole thing and rewrite it using the right approach that simply uses a list of parsed words; or for someone to figure out what all these cryptically named variable are, each one's intended purpose, and what the hidden logical flaw is.

Comment: This code leaks `nn` (and there is no need for `nn` anyway), and `nn[i] == '\0'` will never be true since `t1` doesn't include the null terminator.

Comment: @Brian Stuff here aren't supposed to be answers. Answers go below in the answer section.

Comment: @FeiXiang why are you addressing me? I am the one who put the downvoted answer below. Here, though, is an example of SO *not* at its best. The haystack answer below is sarcastic, and mine was an SO beginner’s gut-reaction post when I saw a typo. That said, if the OP is still reading this: 1) Others are right to simply say: simplify and clarify your code. Use meaningful variable names, etc. 2) Once you do that, are you still having issues detecting the null terminator?

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

size_t count_occurrences(std::string const & haystack, std::string const & needle)
{
    std::size_t count{};
    std::size_t offset{};
    auto const needle_len{ needle.length() };
    auto const hs_len{ haystack.length() };

    if (!(needle_len && hs_len))
        return 0;

    while ((offset = haystack.find(needle, offset)) != std::string::npos) {
        if (hs_len == needle_len)
            return 1;
        if ((!offset && (std::isspace(haystack[needle_len]) || std::ispunct(haystack[needle_len])) ) ||
            ( offset + needle_len == hs_len ) ||
            ( offset && std::isspace(haystack[offset - 1]) &&
            ( std::isspace(haystack[offset + needle_len]) || std::ispunct(haystack[offset + needle_len])) ) )
            ++count;
        offset += needle.length();
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You have it written as:

```
if(nn[i] == ' ' || n[i] == '\0')
```

That has a single `n` character in it.

Comment: Fixing a typo doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Unless the typo is the problem? I doubt he rewrote the code just to post here.

Comment: He has results from the code and is asking how to eliminate an issue. No mention of a compile error.